# Automate creating subtables based on values of one column

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose i have a df with a column X with the following unique values ('A', 'B', 'C')

I want to create a function that will create dataframes containing only the items for such unique value of column X. How best to do this?

I would usually write line of codes by filtering it but I want to know how best to manage this.

Comment: `dict(list(df.groupby('X')))`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sub_dfs = [df[df['X']== i] for i in list(df['X'].unique())]
```

Comment: It's poorly efficient as it needs to read the whole thing for each unique value ;)